# In Google Sheets, how can I output an array of IMPORTJSON() calls using a column as reference?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I hope the question is clear, if not let me know so I can rewrite.

I am using `IMPORTJSON()` from Github:
https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON

What I want to do seems possible to do with `HYPERLINK()`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    HYPERLINK("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/pegas/"&QUERY(
        {A2:A},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
        )
    )
```

I Want to build an array of `IMPORTJSON()` calls the same way.
You'd think I should be able to do this the same way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    ImportJSON("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/pegas/"&QUERY(
        {A2:A},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"),
        "/energy", "noHeaders")
        )
```

[image]

But I'm getting some errors. ATM its displaying:

```
Exception: Request failed for 
https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io returned code 404. 
Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
     <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>Error</title> 
        </head> 
    <body> 
        <pre>Cannot GET /v1/pegas/923195,https://api-apo... 
            (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) 
            (line 217).
```

Another thing I tried, check `Sheet2`, was to simplify the call with this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ImportJSON({E2:E}))
```

Where `E2:E` is the list of URLs built with `HYPERLINK()`.
With this I also get an error:

```
Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length. (line 217).
```

So maybe `ÌMPORTJSON()` does not allow for building an array?
Is there a work around for this situation or is there something wrong with my formulas?

Demo file here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OVXk9MVRtVXiOl-btz3BI33UZu-c2F6Nro4jRZBmMsk/edit

EDIT:

I accepted Mike's solution but I changed it a bit to suit my needs:

```
function importAllJSONArray(url) {
  var listUrls = Array.isArray(url) ? url.flat() : [url]
  var listXpath = []
  var result = []
  listUrls.forEach((address, i) => {
    var prov = []
    var json = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(address).getContentText())
    if (i == 0) { 
      listXpath = Object.keys(json); 
      result.push(listXpath)
    }
    listXpath.forEach(xp => {
      prov.push(json[xp])
    })
    result.push(prov)
  })
  return result
}
```

Comment: You can't build arrayformula with this complex script.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you. If you notice the Spreadsheet I shared is anonymous not from my account. Also I added an image now hope it's better this way.

Comment: You can add support easily by  adding another function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your own arrayformula as follows

```
=arrayformulaJson(A2:A7,B1:D1)
```

code.gs

```
function arrayformulaJson(ids,xpath) {
  listIds = Array.isArray(ids) ? ids.flat() : [ids]
  listXpath = Array.isArray(xpath) ? xpath.flat() : [xpath]
  var result = []
  listIds.forEach(id => {
    var prov = []
    var json = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/pegas/' + id).getContentText())
    listXpath.forEach(xp => {
      prov.push(json[xp])
    })
    result.push(prov)
  })
  return result
};
```

[image]

### edit:

to import the whole JSON including headers

```
=arrayformulaAllJson(A2:A7)
```

note that the result includes the headers, you may put the formula one row before the range

```
function arrayformulaAllJson(ids) {
  var listIds = Array.isArray(ids) ? ids.flat() : [ids]
  var listXpath = []
  var result = []
  listIds.forEach((id, i) => {
    var prov = []
    var json = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/pegas/' + id).getContentText())
    if (i == 0) { 
      listXpath = Object.keys(json); 
      result.push(listXpath)
    }
    listXpath.forEach(xp => {
      prov.push(json[xp])
    })
    result.push(prov)
  })
  return result
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make this custom function to reference a range like ```=myArrayFormula(A2:A)``` ? It looks like ```[headers, ...data]``` is automatically getting the range from ```A2:A```. How can one reference this via formula to another range? I have no idea how to change ```[headers, ...data]``` in a way that allows me to choose the range. GAS is a bit too much for my skills.

Comment: done, let me know if that fit your request

Comment: Sorry Mike but for me it is not displaying anything after "Loading…". I used my demo file and my own sheet and it's the same.

Comment: you have to put parameters as you wish in B1:D1. But you can only put one or more than one according to your need. I have put them in the demo file.

Comment: Ok I see how it works now thank you. Is there a way to import the whole JSON including headers without the ```B1:D1``` range being specified?  Like ```=arrayformulaJson(A2:A7)``` and then I'd use something like ```INDEX()``` or ```OFFSET()``` or ```QUERY()``` or a combination of these to get the values I want.

Comment: Well it still isn't ok but it's my fault because I did not write the question well. Just realized now the API this will be used for is a GraphQL API not REST API like the one I used for the demo file. This script is not working for a GraphQL API. IMPORTJSON does work for GraphQL API but does not accept arrays. I changed a bit your script so it could reference the URL only and not the IDs. I will write another question referencing your script and asking for it to work for GraphQL as I have no idea how to do it or what are the differences really. Thanks a lot Mike this is twice I get your help.

Comment: I placed another question specifically for a GraphQL situation if you wan't to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72903815/in-google-sheets-how-to-output-an-array-of-graphql-api-calls-using-a-column-as

Answer (score 1):

You can support arrays on any custom function using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
/**
 * Adapts importjson to support arrays
 * Restriction: A url should only return one value
 *
 * @customfunction
 */
const importjsonArray = (urls, ...args) =>
  Array.isArray(urls)
    ? urls.map((url) => importjsonArray(url, ...args))
    : String(ImportJSON(urls, ...args));
```

#### Usage:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTJSONARRAY("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/pegas/"&A2:A3,"/energy","noHeaders"))
```

#### Input:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| **A2** | 923195 |
| **A3** | 964911 |

#### Output:

|  | A | B2:"=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTJSONARRAY("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/pegas/"&A2:A3,"/energy","noHeaders")) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A2** | 923195 | 25 |
| **A3** | 964911 | 4 |

Comment: I wish I could understand this.

Comment: @Verminous Just copy paste it.

Comment: Ok I just did it. Your code is so minimalist I thought that you were giving me a base on which I should then code the rest. But actually if I just copy paste it it does something. But what is does is it imports the headers in a single string all bungled up if I just use the URL as argument. I tried to add a 2nd argument like "energy" and it returns nothing. Maybe I'm using it wrong?

Comment: @Verminous 1.How are you calling it? Quote the formula? 2. Can you give a working formula sample of plain importjson?

Comment: ```=importjsonArray("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/pegas/"&Sheet1!A2)```

Comment: Ok so with this one I import the whole Json table and then I offset it with ```INDEX()``` to get just the headers. But I can do this with any row. This is just an example: ```=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(ImportJSON("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/pegas/"&Sheet1!A2),1,0))```.  Here is a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngqsr.jpg

Comment: @Verminous Try `=ImportJSONARRAY(E2:E10,"/energy", "noHeaders")` where E2:E10 is the list of already concatenated formula.

Comment: Ok that works. To apply this as final solution I need this to get a whole Json and not just "energy". I tried ```=ImportJSONARRAY(TheMaster!D2:D13,"", "noHeaders")``` but it imports the whole Json into a single cell rather than spread the info into different cells like ```ÌMPORTJSON()``` does.

Comment: @Verminous use `=SPLIT()`